# Site Users Web Part shows users that don't have access to site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

We have a site collection called: `http://share/sites/Inventory` and within that site collection is a subsite: `http://share/sites/Inventory/HR`.

This subsite has a site users web part.  This web part is listing two individuals that not only don't have access to the subsite, they don't even have access to the site collection.

I did check permissions for both users and SharePoint is telling me that they don't have access.

Any idea why these guys might be showing up and how they can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Check if these users have a unique permission for a specific list within your sub site.

to check permission for specific users go to site settings > users and permissions > Site Permissions

[image]

Also, you might need to run Full User Profile Synchronization service from Central Administration.

Comment: I did attempt this and neither one has any permissions.

Comment: are you tried to run UPSs ?

Comment: Yes, I also ran full UPS.